"Could not find a linkable openssl."
configure: Now, we'll look for OpenSSL >= 1.0.1
checking for openssl directory... configure: WARNING: Could not find a linkable openssl.  If you have it installed somewhere unusual, you can specify an explicit path using --with-openssl-dir
configure: error: Missing libraries; unable to proceed.

When I specify --with-openssl-dir, it still gives the same error.

If you want an automated tool for building a static Tor, take a look at this: https://github.com/cretz/tor-static -- I successfully built static binaries for both Windows and Linux, you could try to install Cygwin and even Cygwin under Wine for building a static binary for Windows, as MSYS doesn't install in Wine as I could notice.

Old bug: there're also two arguments for include and lib directories for OpenSSL, use them without this key and it will work. Same thing with Libevent. Triggers quite frequently especially when building fully-static Tor
